# createAsyncThunk redux-toolkite issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I've read a lot of articles, watched videos regarding to createAsyncThunk, but I have a question about rejected function. How can i handle it? How can i trigger it, because every time fulfilled is triggered, no matter of the request status... Yes, I know, it's have a lot of different solutions around that, but I want to complete the task exactly with this approach, using pending, fullfiled and rejected functions.
Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxbH1.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code using markdown rather than providing a screenshot. This way people can more easily fix your code. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [Fetch_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), so most likely your problem is:

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've fixed the issue, but also added a rejectWithValue within the catch block!